# Bravo For Buckets!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, steganography

> Real or dream? From clouds I dangle:
>   Ordered palette, scarf of angel.
>   Yelp no more, cease to lower!
>   Grey skies gone- I'm Heaven's endower:
>   Blushing bridge where larks embower.
>   Indiscreet, by glitz I govern.
>   Violent deluge, my ban's eterne!

Although a solution to the riddle above is appreciated, the tick will go to the one who explains why the title fits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The riddle is, as already noted:

> [Re]al or dream? From clouds I [d]angle:
>  [Or]dered palette, scarf of [ange]l.
>  [Yel]p no more, cease to [low]er!
>  [Gre]y skies gone- I'm Heaven's [en]dower:
>  [Blu]shing bridge where larks [e]mbower.
> [Indi]screet, by glitz I [go]vern.
> [Viol]ent deluge, my ban's [et]erne!

That is to say,

> Each line takes the first part of the first and last word to form the Thing™ for that line. Taken together, they give ...
>  The colors of the RAINBOW.

The title, and the relevance:

> First part and last part of the title together gives BRACKETS, which is why I outlined the Thing™ texts in brackets above.

Comment: so ... I got the right answer, but I'm not happy with it :)  the rule should have applied to the title too, but of course there's nothing meaningful you can make with the first parts of Bravo and Buckets.  Other than that, a fun puzzle - thanks

Comment: I would say light ray spectrum - VIBGYOR

Comment: "Bracing Beats On A Kettledrum" perhaps?

Comment: @Rubio: I was actually thinking to think of synonyms for "Bravo" and "Buckets" which would yield something meaningful, but I guess we were thinking too much into this. :)

Answer (score 10):

> **Re**al or dream? From clouds I **d**angle: -**RED**
> **Or**dered palette, scarf of **ange**l. -**ORANGE**
> **Yel**p no more, cease to **low**er! -**YELLOW**
> **Gre**y skies gone- I'm Heaven's **en**dower: -**GREEN**
> **Blu**shing bridge where larks **e**mbower. -**BLUE**
> **Indi**screet, by glitz I **go**vern. -**INDIGO**
> **Viol**ent deluge, my ban's **et**erne! -**VIOLET**

Which gives

> the seven colors of **RAINBOW (VIBGYOR)**

Explanation of title

> RAINBOW normally comes after heavy rain (bucket). So rainbows can be considered as bravo for buckets

Answer (score 4):

The solution is:

> A Rainbow (the first letters of each line spell out the sequence of colors in a rainbow)

Partial explanation of title:

> Each line of the riddle has the respective color hidden, as follows:
>  **Re**al or dream? From clouds I **d**angle - Red
>  **Or**dered palette, scarf of **ange**l - Orange
>  **Yel**p no more, cease to **low**er! - Yellow
>  **Gre**y skies gone - I'm Heaven's **en**dower - Green
>  **Blu**shing bridge where larks **e**mbower - Blue
>  **Indi**screet, by glitz I **go**vern - Indigo
>  **Viol**ent deluge, my ban's **et**erne! - Violet

The above suggests that:

> Mixing letters from the front half of 'Bravo' and 'Buckets' should yield something?